# iOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken get token string?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I've finally got `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` calling successfully, and it appears the `deviceToken` isn't `nil`. Now I need to be able to send the device token to my server so it can use it to send push notifications. How do I turn the `deviceToken` `NSData*` value into a string that I can use?

I tried this:

```
NSString* deviceTokenString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:deviceToken encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but this results in `deviceTokenString` being `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
NSMutableString *tokenStr = [[NSMutableString alloc]
                                  initWithCapacity:deviceToken.length * 2];
char *bytes = malloc(deviceToken.length);
[deviceToken getBytes:bytes length:deviceToken.length*2];
for (NSUInteger byteCounter = 0; byteCounter < deviceToken.length; byteCounter++){
    char byte = bytes[byteCounter];
    [tokenStr appendFormat:@"%02hhX", byte];
}
NSLog(@"Token = %@", tokenStr);
```